# Open new tabs in main gmome-terminal window from main gmome-panel?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, tabs

When you open a terminal from the panel in gnome-session-fallback you get a new gnome-terminal window. My goal is to have every subsequent gnome-terminal open from the panel to open as a tab in the already open window if one exists or to create a new window if one doesn't exist.

I have tried the **--tab** notion found in the help pages but this just opens new windows.  I have tried to also use **--tab-with-profile=Default** on the default profile.  Both of these again just open new windows.

I am fully aware that I can create new tabs via keyboard shortcuts.  I am not looking to use them at the moment.